# Need help on this math question about operations on magnitudes

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Let $z$ and $w$ be complex numbers satisfying $|z| = 5, |w| = 2,$ and $z\overline{w} = 6+8i.$ Then enter in the numbers $$\left[|z+w|^2, |zw|^2, |z-w|^2, \left| \dfrac{z}{w} \right|^2 \right]$$ below, in the order listed above. If any of these cannot be uniquely determined from the information given, enter in a question mark.

By plugging in numbers ($z=5$ and $w=2$), I got the following:

I got 49 for the first one, 100 for the second one, 9 for the 3rd one, and 6.25 for the 4th one. But it was wrong, so I don't know how to do this question.

Comment: Hi! Your comment (and other's comments) helped me to successfully answer problem 1, but I still do not understand problem 2. What is the point of the zw=6+8i? It doesn't seem to be used in any of the expressions in the question. All I see being used is plugging in the 5 and the 2. So that's what I don't get and need help on.

Comment: As I wrote, $z \overline{w} = 6+8\,\mathrm{i}$ places a constraint on the real and imaginary components of $z$ and $w$.  That constraint fixes the angle between $z$ and $w$.  Other answers showed you how to write $|z+w|$ in terms of $|z|^2$, $|z\overline{w}|$, $|\overline{z}w| = |\overline{z \overline{w}}|$ and $|w|^2$.  There was nothing left to explain for the second question.

Comment: Additionally, we didn't supply **comments**; we supplied **answers**.

Comment: Do you think there's anything I should learn BEFORE I attempt this question again. It seems like I'm not understanding something that's required to understand you and the other's answers/comments. Is there something I need to be proficient at before doing this problem?

Comment: Your work there and here make it clear you do not understand that there are many different complex numbers with the same magnitude.  If you do not follow the argument in my answer using components, you show unfamiliarity moving between [Cartesian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_number#Cartesian_complex_plane) and [polar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_number#Polar_complex_plane) representations of complex numbers.  You also seem to have weakness manipulating [absolute values](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_value).

Comment: Thank you, I will be sure to review those topics!